# Assigning Pandas dataframe cells with input from other dataframe elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a Pandas df column using information stored in both this same df and an external df.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([["1/1/2019","1st Shift"],["1/1/2019","2nd Shift"],["1/1/2019","3rd Shift"],["1/2/2019","1st Shift"],["1/2/2019","2nd Shift"],["1/2/2019","3rd Shift"],["1/3/2019","1st Shift"],["1/3/2019","2nd Shift"],["1/3/2019","3rd Shift"]],columns=["date","shift"])

       date      shift
0  1/1/2019  1st Shift
1  1/1/2019  2nd Shift
2  1/1/2019  3rd Shift
3  1/2/2019  1st Shift
4  1/2/2019  2nd Shift
5  1/2/2019  3rd Shift
6  1/3/2019  1st Shift
7  1/3/2019  2nd Shift
8  1/3/2019  3rd Shift

lookup_df=pd.DataFrame([["1/1/2019","Andy","Barry","Charley"],["1/1/2019","Barry","Charley","Andy"],["1/1/2019","Andy","Barry","Charley"]],columns=["date","1st Shift","2nd Shift","3rd Shift"])

       date 1st Shift 2nd Shift 3rd Shift
0  1/1/2019      Andy     Barry   Charley
1  1/2/2019     Barry   Charley      Andy
2  1/3/2019      Andy     Barry   Charley
```

My desired result is to add the data from lookup_df into df:

```
       date      shift    staff
0  1/1/2019  1st Shift     Andy
1  1/1/2019  2nd Shift    Barry
2  1/1/2019  3rd Shift  Charley
3  1/2/2019  1st Shift    Barry
4  1/2/2019  2nd Shift  Charley
5  1/2/2019  3rd Shift     Andy
6  1/3/2019  1st Shift     Andy
7  1/3/2019  2nd Shift    Barry
8  1/3/2019  3rd Shift  Charley
```

However, when I try:

```
df["staff"]=lookup_df[(lookup_df["date"]==df["date"])][df["shift"]]
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First unstack the lookup_df

```
lookup_df = lookup_df.set_index("date").unstack().reset_index()
lookup_df.columns = ["shift", "date", "staff"]
```

Then merge the both data frames

```
new_df = pd.merge(df, lookup_df, how="inner", on=["date", "shift"])
```